# using EXISTS with alias in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, alias, exists

I am just trying to limit the data by using the exists clause but it doesn't seem to recognise the alias inside the EXISTS clause ( as it would have in Oracle )

I'm using this sql

```
select count(1) from 
 (select distinct 
         case when qp_cguid is null then ssid else qp_cguid end cguid,
         case when qp_vid is null then vid else qp_vid end as visit_id,
         TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_date_time) visit_date_time
      from `zone1.table1` as t1
      where _partitiontime in ( timestamp( '2019-01-01') )
    and case when qp_vid is null then vid else qp_vid end is not null 
    and case when qp_cguid is null then ssid else qp_cguid end is not null 
    and exists
            (
             select 1 from `zone2.ga_temp` AS    ga 
             where ga.cguid = t1.cguid 
  and (t1.visit_date_time between TIMESTAMP_ADD(ga.min_hit_time_utc, INTERVAL -10 SECOND) and TIMESTAMP_ADD(ga.max_hit_time_utc, INTERVAL 10 SECOND))
            )
)
```

which gives me this error

> "Name cguid not found inside t1"

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
WITH zone2 AS (
  select cguid from `zone2.ga_temp` AS ga 
),
zone1 AS (
  select distinct 
   case when qp_cguid is null then ssid else qp_cguid end cguid,
   case when qp_vid is null then vid else qp_vid end as visit_id,
   TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_date_time) visit_date_time
  from `zone1.table1` as t1
  where _partitiontime in ( timestamp( '2019-01-01') )
    and case when qp_vid is null then vid else qp_vid end is not null 
    and case when qp_cguid is null then ssid else qp_cguid end is not null 
)
SELECT count(1) FROM zone1 INNER JOIN zone2 ON zone1.cguid = zone2.cguid 
WHERE 
  and (zone1.visit_date_time between TIMESTAMP_ADD(ga.min_hit_time_utc, INTERVAL -10 SECOND) and TIMESTAMP_ADD(ga.max_hit_time_utc, INTERVAL 10 SECOND))
```

Comment: @ Nik M. Hope my answer was helpful, note: important on SO - you can mark accepted answer by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. See [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235) for why it is important